# Error while starting kafka cluster:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: apache-kafka, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to start kafka cluster on my local machine having ubuntu 18.04 with intellij 2019. I have kafka 2.3. I already started zookeeper before it. I am trying to run a shell script having below code :
`kafka-server-start.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/server-0.properties`.

I am getting below error :

````
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/vagrant/app/apache-hive-3.0.0-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/vagrant/app/kafka23/libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.26.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2020-06-08T13:36:09,329 INFO [main] kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$ - Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean
2020-06-08T13:36:09,548 ERROR [main] kafka.Kafka$ - Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object;
        at kafka.Kafka$.getPropsFromArgs(Kafka.scala:43) [kafka_2.12-2.3.0.jar:?]
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67) [kafka_2.12-2.3.0.jar:?]
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala) [kafka_2.12-2.3.0.jar:?]```

Can somebody please help to resolve this issue ?
````

Comment: Have you added the kafka home variable ?

Comment: Yes I added it in my bashrc file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I found out was multiple sl4j binding coming from my bashrc file. Both hive and kafka sl4j bindings caused the conflict. I commented the relevant hive code in my bashrc and was able to create kafka cluster.